# Which version of Java is compatible with JDBC 3.0 (MySQL 5.0)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-5.0

I need to connect to an old (non upgradable) version of MySQL (5.0) and I'm struggling to understand which Java version I can use.

for MySQL 5.0 the JDBC supported is the 3.0 (https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-java-connection.php) so I'm figuring out if I can use Java 17 or I have to use a previous version like Java 11.

Comment: I wouldn't think this is a "java version" issue; it's more a "Connector/J JDBC Driver version" issue. The Oracle website doesn't provide compatibility info for old versions of MySQL. In the worst case scenario, you can still try a 5.x driver from [Maven Central Repository](https://search.maven.org/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java).

Answer (score 0):

The lastest connector which supports JRE 8 or higher should be compatible with MySQL 5 :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html